# my code for youtube embeded in multiple iframes is not working . I want youtube video must play when I hover over it and pause when hover out

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, mouseover, youtube-iframe-api, mouseout

I want youtube video embeded in multiple iframes on pageload to be played when  my mouse hover over it and pause when hover out. My below code works, but on pageload  i have to click somewhere on the page.  What I want is, without click, the page should respond to my mouseover and mouseout event.  Can any one help me to do this.

```
<html>

<script src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Youtube player API -->
<script src="//www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<body>

<!-- embeded player1 -->
<div id="player0" name="vp" onmouseover="Mouseover(this)" onmouseout="Mouseout(this)" videoId="K-0Mp075kPQ">
<iframe title="YouTube video player" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" onload="iFrameResize()" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<p></p>
<!-- embeded player2 -->
<div id="player1" name="vp" onmouseover="Mouseover(this)" onmouseout="Mouseout(this)" videoId="fg4CehuZORA">
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" onload="iFrameResize()" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>



<script>

jQuery(document).ready(initYoutubePlayer);

function initYoutubePlayer() {
jQuery('div[name="vp"]').each(function(){
let vid =jQuery(this).attr('videoId');
let player = new YT.Player(this, {
height: '250',
width: '640',
enablejsapi: 1,
videoId: vid,

playerVars: {
  'controls': 0, 
  'rel': 0,
  'playlist': vid,
  'loop': 1,
  'modestbranding': 1,
  'play':1

  
},


});

})
}
Mouseover = (el) => {
let yt_object = YT.get(el.id)
yt_object.playVideo();
}

Mouseout = (el) => {
let yt_object = YT.get(el.id)
yt_object.pauseVideo();
}

jQuery(document).ready(initYoutubePlayer);





</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To play video with a mouseover without any click you should first remove the onload function and call the `initYoutubePlayer()` function as the document gets ready. Also remove the `play:1` parameter from the playerVars object because it will play video automatically as the page load.

Check this one:

```html
<html>

<script src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Youtube player API -->
<script src="//www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<body>

<!-- embeded player1 -->
<div id="player0" name="vp" onmouseover="Mouseover(this)" onmouseout="Mouseout(this)" videoId="K-0Mp075kPQ">
<iframe title="YouTube video player" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<p></p>
<!-- embeded player2 -->
<div id="player1" name="vp" onmouseover="Mouseover(this)" onmouseout="Mouseout(this)" videoId="fg4CehuZORA">
    <iframe title="YouTube video player" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>


<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    initYoutubePlayer();
});

function initYoutubePlayer() {
    jQuery('div[name="vp"]').each(function(){
        let vid =jQuery(this).attr('videoId');
        let player = new YT.Player(this, {
        height: '250',
        width: '640',
        enablejsapi: 1,
        videoId: vid,

        playerVars: {
            'controls': 0, 
            'rel': 0,
            'playlist': vid,
            'loop': 1,
            'modestbranding': 1
        },
        });
    });
}

Mouseover = (el) => {
    let yt_object = YT.get(el.id)
    yt_object.playVideo();
}

Mouseout = (el) => {
    let yt_object = YT.get(el.id)
    yt_object.pauseVideo();
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this resolve your issue

Comment: I applied your suggestions to the code.  But even this is not working. I have to click the page then only the mouseover and mouse events get triggered. I want mouseover and mouseout event to triggered without clicking on the page and only when i hover over the iframe.

Comment: Attach the mouseover and mouseout event listeners to that container instead of the iframe. If the problem still persisted, try using `pointer-events: none` css property on iframe.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox my terminal says

> Autoplay is only allowed when approved by the user, the site is activated by the user, or media is muted.

This is an intentional feature of the browser to prevent malicious or poorly made websites from playing media when the user doesn't want it to.

If this project is only for personal use you can disable this policy, but if this is intended for random users it seems impossible.